# Format date time JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime-format

How to format date and time like this in JavaScript ?

> March 05, 2012 @ 14:30 (UTC - 9:30)

I use this code to calculate EST time :

```
function getDate() {
    var now = new Date();
  var  utc = now.getTime() + (now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

    return new Date(utc + (3600000 * -4));
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Hiya, hope this helps, - http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format , cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 4):

I use the date-time-format that Tats recommended because doing it manually is a huge PIA.

```
var yourDate = dateFormat(getDate(), "mmmm dd, yyyy @ HH:MM) + "(UTC -9:30)";
```

Keep in mind this isn't Daylight Savings aware.. and you are asking for UTC -9:30 in your format, but your function converts to -4. Also, I believe that now.getTime returns in UTC.. so you can just add your difference there.

[JavaScript Date Format](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/)! It's a really powerful little library for working with Dates in JavaScript.

To get today's date in EST, you can do something like...

```
var today = new Date();
today.toString();         // outputs "Wed Apr 11 2012 15:40:40 GMT-0500 (CDT)"


today.setTimezone("EST");
today.toString();         // outputs "Wed Apr 11 2012 14:40:40 GMT-0500 (CDT)"
```

---

Also, its worth mentioning to checkout [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). I think the two libraries complement each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you do just

```
var now = new Date();
document.write(now);
```

you will get

```
Wed Mar 14 2012 20:53:06 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

[Link1](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp), [Link2](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp).

Is it what you want?

Comment: I need EST time , I found my answer btw thanks for your attention.

Comment: @shaahin... can you post your solution?