# Split the date in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to split the below date format into day date and time.

Date Format is like "`2013-05-07T11:04:00+05:30`"
I want to display above date like "`Tue,7 May 2013, 11.04AM`".
Please suggest how to do this in java script or jquery

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: go through date.js ..   https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation ...come in handy related to javascript Date stuff

Comment: It's already asked on [Format date time JavaScript][1]. Check it out there are some useful answers.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709989/format-date-time-javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can use this very useful little library:

http://momentjs.com/

Example:

```
moment("2013-05-07T11:04:00+05:30", "MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
```

Comment: I have used moment as shown in above. i used alert to print.i got "61535982570000". My code is like this " var date=moment("2013-05-07T11:04:00+05:30", "MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"); alert(date); The date i am getting dynamically.

Comment: Try with the format function: moment("2013-05-07T11:04:00+05:30").format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");

Answer (score 1):

You should work with the [native Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) - this is the easiest way to handle the string.

You can do the following:

```
var date = new Date("2013-05-07T11:04:00+05:30");
```

now you have several Date methods you can use to format your string and get the information you need, e.g. what you want is:

```
date.toUTCString()
// output:
"Tue, 07 May 2013 05:34:00 GMT"
```

You also could use a regex or an external library, but probably the best way (imo!) is to simply work with the Date Object.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use `Date.parse(string)`, *but* there is no way to determine what date/time  formats a particular JavaScript implementation supports.

Otherwise:

- Use a regex to break up (and validate) the string, convert each string component into a `Number` and then pass to the `Date` constructor taking separate components.
- Use a library that implements the previous option (eg. see other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16415392/67392)).

Comment: Any JavaScript implementation that supports ECMAScript 5 will support ISO8601 formatting passed to `Date.parse()`, however others may or may not support this feature (such as IE<=8).  For actually formatting the string, using a custom function is recommended, as the native `Date` methods are implementation dependent in their formatting of dates.

Answer (score 0):

moment.js could be a good choice for you, for example:

Actual moment:

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
```

Format:

```
moment("2013-05-07T11:04:00+05:30", "MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
```