# Formatting a Date String in React Native

Tags: date, react-native

I'm trying to format a Date String in React Native.

Ex: 2016-01-04 10:34:23

Following is the code I'm using.

```
var date = new Date("2016-01-04 10:34:23");
console.log(date);
```

My problem is, when I'm emulating this on a iPhone 6S, it'll print Mon `Jan 04 2016 10:34:23 GMT+0530 (IST)` without any problem. But if I try with the iPhone 5S it prints nothing. And if you try to get the month by using a method like `date.getMonth()` it'll print `"NaN"`.

Why is this? What is the workaround?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

The beauty of the React Native is that it supports lots of JS libraries like Moment.js. 
Using moment.js would be a better/easier way to handle date/time instead coding from scratch

just run this in the terminal (`yarn add moment` also works if using React's built-in package manager):

```
npm install moment --save
```

And in your React Native js page:

```
import Moment from 'moment';

render(){
    Moment.locale('en');
    var dt = '2016-05-02T00:00:00';
    return(<View> {Moment(dt).format('d MMM')} </View>) //basically you can do all sorts of the formatting and others
}
```

You may check the moment.js official docs here
https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Moment is great but very large for common usages, and unfortunately not modular so you have to import the whole package to use it. Consider using date-fns (https://date-fns.org/) instead. It is modular, so you can just `import { format } from 'date-fns'` and `format(new Date(), 'MMMM Do, YYYY H:mma')`, etc.

Comment: @MattRabe you should have added this as an answer. Another difference I found is Moment seems to be applicable only in HTML and date-fns can be used everywhere in a component.

Comment: Keep in mind the lowercase 'd' is Day of Week not Day of Month 'D'.

Comment: moment no longer supported https://momentjs.com/docs/

Answer (score 57):

### Easily accomplished using a package.

Others have mentioned Moment. Moment is great but very large for a simple use like this, and unfortunately not modular so **you have to import the whole package to use any of it**.

I recommend using date-fns (https://date-fns.org/) (https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns). It is light-weight and modular, so you can import only the functions that you need.

### In your case:

**Install it**: `npm install date-fns --save`

**In your component:**

```
import { format } from "date-fns";

var date = new Date("2016-01-04 10:34:23");

var formattedDate = format(date, "MMMM do, yyyy H:mma");

console.log(formattedDate);
```

Substitute the format string above `"MMMM do, yyyy H:mma"` with whatever format you require.

#### Update: v1 vs v2 format differences

v1 used `Y` for year and `D` for day, while v2 uses `y` and `d`. Format strings above have been updated for v2; the equivalent for v1 would be `"MMMM Do, YYYY H:mma"` (source: https://blog.date-fns.org/post/unicode-tokens-in-date-fns-v2-sreatyki91jg/). Thanks @Red

Comment: Indeed. Also can't believe this was 4 years ago. Although with this project Moment became quite useful, with timezone utilities etc.

Answer (score 32):

There is no need to include a bulky library such as Moment.js to fix such a simple issue.

The issue you are facing is not with formatting, but with parsing.

As John Shammas mentions in another answer, the `Date` constructor (and `Date.parse`) are picky about the input. Your `2016-01-04 10:34:23` may work in one JavaScript implementation, but not necessarily in the other.

[According to the specification of ECMAScript 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2), `Date.parse` supports (a simplification of) ISO 8601. That's good news, because your date is already very ISO 8601-like.

All you have to do is change the input format just a little. Swap the space for a `T`: `2016-01-04T10:34:23`; and optionally add a time zone (`2016-01-04T10:34:23+01:00`), otherwise UTC is assumed.

Answer (score 8):

Write below function to get date in string, convert and return in string format.

```
getParsedDate(strDate){
    var strSplitDate = String(strDate).split(' ');
    var date = new Date(strSplitDate[0]);
    // alert(date);
    var dd = date.getDate();
    var mm = date.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!

    var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
    }
    date =  dd + "-" + mm + "-" + yyyy;
    return date.toString();
}
```

**Print it where you required:**
Date : {this.getParsedDate(stringDate)}

Answer (score 4):

A lightweight alternative for `momentjs` is `dayjs`

You can install it by using either **yarn** or **npm**

```bash
yarn add dayjs
# or
npm install --save dayjs
```

```js
import dayjs from "dayjs";

dayjs("2016-01-04 10:34:23").format("d MMM");
// 4 Jan
```

Answer (score 3):

The Date constructor is very picky about what it allows. The string you pass in must be supported by Date.parse(), and if it is unsupported, it will return NaN. Different versions of JavaScript do support different formats, if those formats deviate from the official ISO documentation.

See the examples here for what is supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 3):

```js
function getParsedDate(date){
  date = String(date).split(' ');
  var days = String(date[0]).split('-');
  var hours = String(date[1]).split(':');
  return [parseInt(days[0]), parseInt(days[1])-1, parseInt(days[2]), parseInt(hours[0]), parseInt(hours[1]), parseInt(hours[2])];
}
var date = new Date(...getParsedDate('2016-01-04 10:34:23'));
console.log(date);
```

> Because of the variances in parsing of date strings, it is recommended
>   to always manually parse strings as results are inconsistent,
>   especially across different ECMAScript implementations where strings
>   like "2015-10-12 12:00:00" may be parsed to as NaN, UTC or local
>   timezone.

... as described in the resource:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution.

````js
/**
 * Instantiates a date Date object, used because doing the following doesn't
 * work in React-Native but does work in the browser.
 * ```
 * // Replace this with
 * var date = new Date('2020-08-11 21:23:00')
 * // with
 * var date = safeNewDate('2020-08-11 21:23:00')
 * ```
 * @param {string} localDateTimeStr
 * @returns {Date}
 */
export const safeNewDate = function(localDateTimeStr) {

  var match = localDateTimeStr.match(
    /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})[\sT](\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})(.(\d+))?/,
  )
  if (!match) throw new Error('Invalid format.')

  var [, year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds, , millseconds] = match

  return new Date(
    year,
    Number(month) - 1,
    date,
    hours,
    minutes,
    seconds,
    millseconds || 0,
  )
}
````

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I handled the following:

```
  const modifiedString = string => {
     const splitString = string.split('...');
     var newStr = '';
     for (var i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++) {
        if (splitString[i] !== '' && splitString[i] !== ' '){
        newStr = (
           <Text style={{ flexDirection: 'row', width: 200 }}>
              <Text>{newStr}</Text>
              <Text>{splitString[i]}</Text>
              <SuperFill data={res[i]} check={checkX} />
           </Text>
           );
        }
     }
   return newStr;
 };
```

My **SuperFill** is a **TextInput**