# React show only time hh: mm from DateTime field in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, model-view-controller

I receive Json data, which contains a date-time field.
Datetime field look like this:

```
2017-05-03T19: 00: 00 + 02: 00
```

In my code below, I get DateTime in "timeStamp"

```
  var options = this.props.options.AvaliabltTime.map(function (app, index) {
                    var timeStamp = new Date(app.AppointmentStart,"hh:mm");
                   return (
                   <div>
                         <button className="timebtn" id={app.AppointmentID}
                                 onClick={this.onEventClick.bind(this)}
                                 style={{ backgroundColor: (app.AppointmentID == this.props.clickedButtonID ? 'green' : '') }}>
                             Kl. {timeStamp}
                         </button>
                   </div>
                   )
                }.bind(this));
```

In code abow, iam trying to show only time hh:mm in {timeStamp}

But it show notning, whats is error ?

Comment: `new Date(app.AppointmentStart,"hh:mm");` is not a [valid call to the global `Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax). This related question http://stackoverflow.com/q/34590369/5217142 could be of help.

Comment: Also the spaces in the date string need to be removed before using it as a date string argument for  `new Date( dateString)`.