# Is there a way to convert date(2022-12-28) to this format 28th December 2022 in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, user-interface, frontend

```
<div className='approval_text'>
 {(getdate && getdate.length > 0) && 
 getdate[0]['START_DATE']}
</div>
```

**Is there a way to convert date(2022-12-28) to this format 28th December 2022 in react-js?**

Comment: Please share your code where are you stuck?

Comment: I am getting date in this format 2022-12-28 from api

Comment: That is your _situation_, the question was where you are actually _stuck_ with this. What has your research turned up so far? Have you looked at f.e. https://stackoverflow.com/q/34590369/1427878 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `moment` to convert your date. Install `moment` from
`npm i moment`.

```
moment(getdate[0]['START_DATE']).format('Do MMMM YYYY')
```

Comment: [moment is dead](https://momentjs.com/docs/)